# Matlab figure can no longer pan or zoom after supertitle added

Tags: matlab, figure

I'm making some figures in Matlab, many of which I'd like to print at different zoom levels. The figure is made using subplot. Each subplot has its own title, but I also want a larger title for the entire figure.

The problem is this: once I add a supertitle, the figure no longer pans or zooms. If I remove the supertitle with `supertitle()`, then I can once again pan and zoom. The brute force solution to this problem is to continue toggling the supertitle on and off while I pan and zoom in between, but this is both time consuming and irritating.

Does anyone know a way to restore the pan and zoom functions while keeping the supertitle of a figure?

Comment: I don't have a function `supertitle` and I have nearly all the toolboxes. I couldn't find it on the file exchange either (the closest was `suptitle()` which does the same thing, but is no longer available). Is that your own function? If so, could you post the function definition? My guess is that the function must not be returning focus back to the original axes, which is why pan/zoom might not be working.

Comment: @yoda I believe this is the problem. I had not realized it was a custom function. If you can post your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it and then ask the person who wrote the function to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, `supertitle()` is not an in-built function in MATLAB and is not shipped with the common toolboxes from Mathworks. This is probably a custom function file that extends MATLAB's plotting capabilities.

That said, the error is most likely due to the function not returning focus to the original plot which makes zoom & pan to not work as desired. The exact reason can only be figured out by looking at the original code.

Comment: This was exactly it. The function created a new set of axes on top of the plot. Moving that to the background instead of the foreground solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try panning and zooming programmatically, rather than using the GUI controls.

Comment: Nope. Whatever this mystery function does prevents panning and zooming in every possible way.